# SQL count with another table in SELECT clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

In my database, have 2 different fields

i.) Employee
ii.) Department

In my `employee` table,

```
NAME      Department
---------------------
John          IT
Siti       Research
Jason      Research
```

In my `Department`,

```
Name
------------
IT
Research
Computer
```

Using statement

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.DNAME
FROM DEPARTMENT,
     EMPLOYEE
WHERE DEPARTMENT.DNAME = EMPLOYEE.DNAME
  AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM EMPLOYEE.DNAME)=0;
```

when no employee in the `department` then will display

```
Name
--------------
Computer
```

Keep trying but having some error on it

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT dname FROM department WHERE dname NOT IN (SELECT dname FROM employee)`?

Comment: missing expression @neel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Two alternatives:**

1. Using `IN`:

   ```
   SELECT name FROM Department
   WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Department 
                      FROM Employee)
   ```
2. Using `Left Join`:

   ```
   SELECT D.NAME 
   FROM DEPARTMENT D LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE ON D.NAME = EMPLOYEE.Department
   WHERE EMPLOYEE.Department IS NULL
   ```

   An example in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/189487/6).

   This method will show higher performance than the other if you have thousands of records in your table.

Comment: The join is most likely faster on MySQL, not as sure about other RDBMS's.

Comment: +1 for the LEFT JOIN with NOT NULL. I will test that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `NOT IN`. Sub query need to be `DISTINCT` to avoid performance    issue in future:

```
SELECT name FROM Department
WHERE name NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM Employee);
```

Or `NOT EXIST`, faster in most cases:

```
SELECT name FROM Department
WHERE NOT EXIST  ( SELECT 1 FROM Employee 
                   WHERE Employee.Department = Department.name);
```

Comment: You should probably move the `DISTINCT` to the outer select, it's as far as I can see not very useful in the `IN` clause. Could you explain what what performance issues you're talking about?

Comment: DISTINCT is to prevent duplicate data isn't

Comment: DISTINCT doesn't _avoid_ performance issues. It can create them because it requires a unique sort.

Comment: When we have very big Department table, with may duplicate Department Name records in Employee table. For each Department, Oracle will check  every record in Sub Query (not sure in other DBMS). If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: And more, Department Name is supposed to be unique in Department table.

Comment: @Ben: There is no absolute here. It could create performance issues :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I didn't say "Oracle would execute the subquery more than once". In fact, Oracle execute the subquery just 1 time. Then do the compare. DISTINCT will help narrow down the number of record need to be compare. And as I said for the second point: "Department Name is supposed to be unique in Department table".

Comment: @MinhD Since performance is always debatable (obviously), esp. across multiple RDBMS's and your query will indeed give the intended result as long as the department name is unique in departments, I'll stop debating things here for everyone's benefit :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Sure. We will have other chances to test our point. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't state your error but you can select all departments that don't appear in the employee table:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.DNAME 
FROM DEPARTMENT 
WHERE DEPARTMENT.DNAME NOT IN (SELECT DEPARTMENT FROM EMPLOYEE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D.Name
FROM Employee E
RIGHT JOIN Department D
ON E.Department=D.Name
WHERE E.Department IS NULL
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ffcb/4)